# Uses for fish bones?

Tags: waste, pets

We eat fish.  I know some small fish bones are fried and eaten as food in some parts of the world, and they can be composted for mineral content.  I do compost some already, but we don’t have that much space for composting and we do have to worry about rats so not much cooked food goes out that way.

In particular I am wondering:

1. Are fish bones good calcium supplements for turtles?
2. Should I consider drying, baking, and grinding as a human calcium supplement?
3. Are there any other uses I am not thinking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about turtles, but let me give you an idea from the world's number one fish eaters again.

In Japan, there are several uses for fish bones (with some meat left on them). The bones plus meat are ground into a paste called [surimi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surimi), which is then processed into [satsuma age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satsuma_age), [chikuwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chikuwa), or similar products (pictures below), which all have a rubber-like consistency. They can be eaten cold in salads (sliced), warm in soups or just for snacks and go well with mustard and/or soy sauce. Fresh they last for about a week in the fridge, but are usually stored in the freezer for several months.

[image: satsuma-age]
<sub>(source: [cybergarden.net](http://www.cybergarden.net/gourmet/images5/DSC45582.JPG))</sub>
[image: chikuwa]

Comment: Hi, could you back up your claim that Surimi is made from fish bones? I read the Wikipedia pages in English and in German, and they both state that Surimi is made exclusively from fish meat and no bones. Also this producer (a random example) http://www.alaskaseafood.org/surimi/about_surimi.html states that his Surimi is made from boneless fillets.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a few years since the OP made this post, but I wanted to add a few thoughts for future readers.

Fish bones can be mounted for education and display.  Photos (and directions) can easily be found online.

They can also be made into sculptures:
http://icelandmag.visir.is/article/icelandic-lego-made-fish-bones

And they can be made into sewing needles as many primitive peoples once did.  Here is some information on bone needles and specifically fishbone needles in this link:  http://paleoplanet69529.yuku.com/topic/1046#.VwSevMfmqM9

Hope the OP sees this!  Enjoy all!

Answer (score 2):

You can bury them directly in your garden. That's what some of the native Americans did in coastal New England.